# do I require Transit visa for Amsterdam since I am travelling from Delhi- Amsterdam- Havana and my layover time at Amsterdam is 1.45 hrs

Tags: netherlands, amsterdam, havana

I am travelling from India to Havana via Amsterdam.the layover time at Amsterdam is 1.45 hrs. Do I require to obtain Transit Visa?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your query ot seems like you are holding Indian passport and ONLY landing on Amsterdam just to boarding another flight destine towards other destinations. 
Have a look on https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/visas-for-the-netherlands/airport-transit-visa

There is details of requirement for anyone touching ground even if for 1.45 hours of time for transit via their airport.

Another details discussion on various aspects of transit system can be found on this answer for other similar query:
https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/30570/48220